# Chartist plugin data point for bar chart

Tags: plugins, charts, chartist.js

I'm trying to get data point to work for bar charts, I found the plugin for line chart, but can't get it to work for bars, can anyone help? the data point should show above the bar. https://jsfiddle.net/x79b1m2w/1/

```
<div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section" id="chart1"></div>
<div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section" id="chart2"></div>

<script>
new Chartist.Bar('#chart1', {
  labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F'],
  series: [8, 19, 24, 37, 12]
}, {
  distributeSeries: true  
});

new Chartist.Line('#chart2', {
  labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F'],
  series: [
    [12, 9, 7, 8, 5]
  ]
}, {
  plugins: [
    Chartist.plugins.ctPointLabels({
      textAnchor: 'middle'
    })
  ]
});
</script>
<script>
(function(window, document, Chartist) {
  'use strict';

  var defaultOptions = {
    labelClass: 'ct-label',
    labelOffset: {
      x: 0,
      y: -10
    },
    textAnchor: 'middle',
    labelInterpolationFnc: Chartist.noop
  };

  Chartist.plugins = Chartist.plugins || {};
  Chartist.plugins.ctPointLabels = function(options) {

    options = Chartist.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);

    return function ctPointLabels(chart) {
      if(chart instanceof Chartist.Line) {
        chart.on('draw', function(data) {
          if(data.type === 'point') {
            data.group.elem('text', {
              x: data.x + options.labelOffset.x,
              y: data.y + options.labelOffset.y,
              style: 'text-anchor: ' + options.textAnchor
            }, options.labelClass).text(options.labelInterpolationFnc(data.value.x === undefined ? data.value.y : data.value.x + ', ' + data.value.y));
          }
        });
      }
            if(chart instanceof Chartist.Bar) {
        chart.on('draw', function(data) {
          if(data.type === 'bar') {
            data.group.elem('text', {
              x: data.x + options.labelOffset.x,
              y: data.y + options.labelOffset.y,
              style: 'text-anchor: ' + options.textAnchor
            }, options.labelClass).text(options.labelInterpolationFnc(data.value.x === undefined ? data.value.y : data.value.x + ', ' + data.value.y));
          }
        });
      }
    };
  };

}(window, document, Chartist));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin to add labels to bar and column charts.

See here: https://github.com/YorkshireInteractive/chartist-bar-labels

I then borrowed the label position calculations from the following github comments:

https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/281

In short, I have the following in the ctBarLabels plugin options:

```
            position: {
            x: function(data) {
                return data.x1 + (data.element.width() * .5);
            },
            y: function(data) {
                return data.y1 + (data.element.height() * -1) - 10;
            }
```

I can now style the labels with a stylesheet. I can also use functions to format the labels (for example, currency vs. the plain value).

Answer (score 0):

Change your plugin code to :

```
if(chart instanceof Chartist.Bar) {
    chart.on('draw', function(data) {
      if(data.type === 'bar') {
        data.group.elem('text', {
          x: (data.x === undefined ? data.x1 : data.x ) + options.labelOffset.x,
          y: (data.y === undefined ? data.y2 : data.y) + options.labelOffset.y,
          style: 'text-anchor: ' + options.textAnchor
        }, options.labelClass).text(options.labelInterpolationFnc(data.value.x === undefined ? data.value.y : data.value.x + ', ' + data.value.y));
      }
    });
  }
```